# Setting keyboard focus to an item that has the class "active" using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

The issue I am having is that I am trying to assign keyboard focus to a bootstrap "active" class using jQuery. The goal is to allow accessibility users who select from a drop menu to go directly to the selected item, and skip the rest.

jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('span').find('.active').focus
});
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 ApplicationSubtabs" style="height:auto">
                <span class="Subtab NoteTab" style="z-index:2;height:auto;">
                    <span id="NotesBtn">Notes</span>
                </span>
                <span class="Subtab DetailTab">
                    <span id="InfoBtn" class="subTabAction">Details</span>
                    <span id="DurationBtn" class="subTabAction">Duration</span>
                    <span id="POCList" class="subTabAction">Points of Contact</span>

                    @if (Model.AdditionalLocations.Count > 1)
                    {
                        <span id="AdditionalLocationsBtn" class="subTabAction">Additional Locations</span>
                    }

                </span>
                <span class="Subtab RequirementTab" style="z-index:2;height:auto;">
                    <span id="EligiblePrograms" class="subTabAction"> Eligible Programs</span>
                    <span id="RateInfo" class="subTabAction">Tuition Rate Info</span>
                    <span id="CurrentRates" class="subTabAction">Institution Tuition Rates</span>
                    <span id="CurrentInstitutionFees" class="subTabAction">Institution Fees</span>
                    <span id="CurrentOtherExpensesPolicy" class="subTabAction">Other Expenses/Policy</span>
                    <span id="CurrentProgramRates" class="subTabAction" @if (!Model.HasProgrammaticRatesCurrent) { @Html.Raw("style='display:none'")  }>Program-Specific Tuition Rates</span>
                </span>
                @if (Model.CurrentInstitutionTuitionRateHeaderId > 0)
                {
                    <span class="Subtab AnnualRequirementTab subTabAction" style="z-index:2;height:auto;">
                        <span id="AnnualEligiblePrograms" class="subTabAction"> Eligible Programs</span>
                        <span id="AnnualRateInfo" class="subTabAction">Tuition Rate Info</span>
                        <span id="AnnualInstitutionRates" class="subTabAction">Institution Tuition Rates</span>
                        <span id="AnnualInstitutionFees" class="subTabAction">Institution Fees</span>
                        <span id="AnnualOtherExpensesPolicy" class="subTabAction">Other Expenses/Policy</span>
                        <span id="AnnualProgrampecificRates" class="subTabAction" @if (!Model.HasProgrammaticRatesAnnual) { @Html.Raw("style='display:none'")  }>Program-Specific Tuition Rates</span>
                    </span>
                }
            </div>
```

Comment: well you do not call focus on the first line... missing the ().. and what is `this('id')`

Comment: That is what was supposed to receive focus. the id of the "active" span is intended to be focused upon, had to correct that. I added focus in a previous attempt directly to the active class span.

Comment: `$('span').find('.active').focus();` <- you need to add the `.` to `active` to find an item with a class of

Comment: `this` has nothing to do with the active span and `this` is not a function. I am guessing the error console would state that for you. Multiple problems there. Next I am guessing the span has the class active not a child of the span. So it should have just been `$("span.active").focus();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` should take a class as a selector and not `active` like an tag element and you also don't call the `focus()` on the first line. Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('span').find('.active').focus();
});
```

Also, `$(this('id'))` is wrong, it should look like `$(this)` or `$(this).attr('id')`, but in this case I don't see the need of using `$(this)`.

**UPDATE**:

For the click event handler you can use:

```
$('.subTabAction').on('click', function(){
     $(this).find('.active').focus();
});
```

Comment: There's no need for `$(this)` in this case, as he gets the element by the active class.

Comment: Edited to correct issue with "this" to better address the problem. The issue is that I am trying to assign by id, because there are multiple "active" tabs in the page, since there are multiple levels of "subtabs"

Comment: @Joshua, then on which element you want to get the `focus()` applied to? Which `id`? And who has the class `active`?

Comment: @Ionut Each set of tabs is attached to another page with a drop menu selector. So, the objective is that if they click on "details" then that subtab will have tab focus, if they select "rateinfo" then that will receive focus, etc...

Comment: @Joshua, I hope I understood you correctly, check my updated answer. If is not what you need please tell and we'll find a solution.

Comment: @Ionut I appreciate your help, testing now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132305/discussion-between-ionut-and-joshua).